# How to Set JSON Array to Defined Type?

Tags: json, jsonschema

How do I set the type of objects in an array to refer to another defined object in the definitions section of a json schema file?  I have tried doing this:

```
"definitions": {
    "ObjectA": {
        "title": "ObjectA",
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
            "description": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "status": {
                "type": "string"
            },
        },
        "required": [
            "description",
            "status"
        ]
    },
    "ObjectB": {
        "title": "ObjectB",
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
            "objectalist": {
                "type": "array",
                "items": {
                    "type": {
                        "$ref": "#/definitions/ObjectA"
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "required": [
            "objectalist"
        ]
    }
}
```

and the json editor seems to think it is fine. This snippet is part of a Swagger API definition and when I run it through the codegen tool, I get this error:

```
[main] ERROR io.swagger.codegen.DefaultCodegen - No Type defined for Property null
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not process model 'ObjectB'.Please make sure that your schema is correct!
        at io.swagger.codegen.DefaultGenerator.generate(DefaultGenerator.java:297)
        at io.swagger.codegen.cmd.Generate.run(Generate.java:223)
        at io.swagger.codegen.SwaggerCodegen.main(SwaggerCodegen.java:36)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at io.swagger.codegen.languages.AbstractJavaCodegen.toModelName(AbstractJavaCodegen.java:400)
        at io.swagger.codegen.languages.AbstractJavaCodegen.getSwaggerType(AbstractJavaCodegen.java:577)
        at io.swagger.codegen.DefaultCodegen.getTypeDeclaration(DefaultCodegen.java:1119)
        at io.swagger.codegen.languages.AbstractJavaCodegen.getTypeDeclaration(AbstractJavaCodegen.java:427)
        at io.swagger.codegen.languages.AbstractJavaCodegen.toDefaultValue(AbstractJavaCodegen.java:440)
        at io.swagger.codegen.DefaultCodegen.fromProperty(DefaultCodegen.java:1359)
        at io.swagger.codegen.DefaultCodegen.addVars(DefaultCodegen.java:2738)
        at io.swagger.codegen.DefaultCodegen.addVars(DefaultCodegen.java:2709)
        at io.swagger.codegen.DefaultCodegen.addVars(DefaultCodegen.java:2695)
        at io.swagger.codegen.DefaultCodegen.fromModel(DefaultCodegen.java:1284)
        at io.swagger.codegen.languages.AbstractJavaCodegen.fromModel(AbstractJavaCodegen.java:601)
        at io.swagger.codegen.DefaultGenerator.processModels(DefaultGenerator.java:875)
        at io.swagger.codegen.DefaultGenerator.generate(DefaultGenerator.java:290)
        ... 2 more
```

If I change ObjectB to:

```
    "ObjectB": {
        "title": "ObjectB",
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
            "objectalist": {
                "type": "array",
                "items": {
                    "type": "string"
                }
            }
        },
        "required": [
            "objectalist"
        ]
    }
```

the codegen works.  Is there a way to set the object type in a array to a defined type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer in another post about defining custom JSON types.  The answer is to remove the enclosing `"type":`. So, it looks like this:

```
"ObjectB": {
        "title": "ObjectB",
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
            "objectalist": {
                "type": "array",
                "items": {
                    "$ref": "#/definitions/ObjectA"
                }
            }
        },
        "required": [
            "objectalist"
        ]
    }
```